# How to return a string as valid JSON from Spring web app?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring endpoint for my REST web services app that I want to return a string:

```
"Unauthorized: token is invalid"
```

But my javascript on the front-end chokes on this:

```
JSON.parse("Unauthorized: token is invalid") //Unexpected token U
```

How do I get my app to return a valid JSON string? Here is my current code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/401")
public ResponseEntity<String> unauthorized() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Unauthorized: token is invalid", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```

Comment: Return an object with a string property

Answer (score 13):

Return a Map instead.

```
Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<String,String>();

result.put("message", "Unauthorized...");

return result;
```

You don't need to return a `ResponseEntity`, you can directly return a POJO or collection. Add `@ResponseBody` to your handler method if you want to return a POJO or collection.

Also, I'd say it's better to use `forward` over `redirect` for errors.

Comment: Maybe `Collections.singletonMap("message", "Unauthorized");` would be better in this case since only a message needs to be returned. Anyways +1

Answer (score 8):

@Neil presents a better alternative to what you are trying to accomplish.

In response to the question asked however, you are close.

The modified code below should produce a valid JSON response

```
@RequestMapping(value="/401")
public ResponseEntity<String> unauthorized() {

    String json = "[\"Unauthorized\": \"token is invalid\"]";
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(json, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```